# Convert Ascii value to Character in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to convert **ascii** value to its **character** in hive.Is there any existing function in a hive (like we have ***char function*** in SQL server).Does anyone knows how to achieve this in a hive?

For Example: For 65 , result would be A.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible by combining a few of the built in functions:

```
Select decode(unhex(hex(65)), 'US-ASCII');
```

`hex` changes the int value to a Hexadecimal string, while `unhex` changes this to binary. then `decode` interprets the binary as ASCII data.

Comment: how to reverse it? i want to replace A with 65

Comment: please ask a separate question

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Hive:

```
SELECT CHR(65)
FROM Table_name;
```