# Hive SQL - Test for \u0000 (ascii 00) without `chr()`

Tags: hive

I have a dataset with some corrupted data - a string column has some strings containing `\u0000`. I need to filter out all of them, and the only thing I have at my disposal is the `where` clause.

I tried `WHERE field NOT LIKE concat('%', chr(00), '%')`, but my hive distro (which is AWS EMR) doesn't recognize `chr()`. Is there another option for filling out my `where` clause to filter out fields containing `\u0000`, without using `chr()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try as follow

```sql
SELECT '\u0000' AS text;

+-------+--+
| text  |
+-------+--+
|      |
+-------+--+
-- NOT EMPTY
```

```sql
SELECT '\u0000abc' AS text;

+-------+--+
| text  |
+-------+--+
| abc  |
+-------+--+
-- NOT EMPTY
```

so

```sql
SELECT text 
FROM(SELECT '\u0000abc' AS text) AS t  
WHERE text NOT LIKE('\u0000%');

+-------+--+
| text  |
+-------+--+
+-------+--+
-- EMPTY
```

```sql
SELECT text 
FROM(SELECT '\u0000abc' AS text) AS t  
WHERE text LIKE('\u0000%');

+-------+--+
| text  |
+-------+--+
| abc  |
+-------+--+
-- NOT EMPTY
```

Comment: Thanks - this is useful, and cleaner than the other option I came up with, which relies on `hex()/unhex()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916754/convert-ascii-value-to-character-in-hive

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

```
WHERE field NOT LIKE '%\000%'
```